# BLAS1-type operations on vectors

Tags: matlab, blas

Does anybody know what is MATLAB using for performing BLAS1-type operations, e.g., `dscal` or `daxpy`?

```
>> a=ones(1,1e6,'double');
>> b=ones(1,1e6,'double');
>> a=2*a;  % dscal
>> a=2*a+1;
>> b=2*b+a; % daxpy
```

I have substituted MATLABs BLAS library using the `BLAS_VERSION` environment variable. I used a custom compiled (and modified) OpenBLAS, and inserted some `printf`s here and there to see if MATLAB is calling the library. I do get a `printf` for matrix-matrix multiplication, but I do not get anything for the simple BLAS1 operations. Which is a shame, because I really need this for performance reasons.

Which makes me wonder - does MATLAB re-implement this basic functionality? What would be a reason for doing so? And finally - where is it implemented and can I pre-load/substitute it?

Comment: In my experience, Matlab has some optimized version of some of the BLAS operations - I do not know where they are, and how they could be accessed, unfortunately.

Comment: I believe that, on the appropriate platforms, Matlab calls either Intel MKL routines or AMD ACML routines.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark using the `BLAS_VERSION` variable effectively substitutes the BLAS that MATLAB uses. So it doesn't use MKL/ACML anymore. At least that is true for the BLAS3 operations - I have checked that. The problem is that the BLAS1 functionality does not seem to be substituted in this way.

Comment: Any difference if you edit `blas.spec` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigation I am now certain that MATLAB does not use BLAS for **all** vector operations (it does use it for some operations - see **Edit** note below). You can verify this under Linux in the following way. Start MATLAB, then

```
>> feature getpid
ans =
   13608
```

From linux terminal check, what dynamic libraries are loaded by MATLAB, or to be precise, check if MKL has been loaded (I am testing on an Intel CPU):

```
$ cat /proc/13608/numa_maps | grep mkl
```

The above returns an empty output, hence mkl is not yet linked. Now, perform a simple operation on vectors:

```
>> a=zeros(1, 1e6, 'double');
>> a=2*a; % dscal
```

and check the libraries again:

```
$ cat /proc/13608/numa_maps | grep mkl
```

Again, the output is empty, so no MKL. You can check that it is the same for other BLAS1 operations. Now, do a BLAS3 operation:

```
>> A=zeros(100);
>> B=A*A';
```

and check the linked libraries for mkl

```
$ cat /proc/13608/numa_maps | grep mkl

7f4b687ec000 prefer:0 file=/home/matlab/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/mklcompat.so
7f4b6afb4000 prefer:0 file=/home/matlab/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/mkl.so
[...]
```

So yes, MATLAB does use BLAS libraries for BLAS3, and no, it does not use it for BLAS1. I have not found any way in which I can substitute MATLABs internal functions for operations on vectors. And I believe there is none. They seem to be implemented in one of the core MATLAB libraries (libmwmcr).

**Edit**
It turns out that BLAS1 libraries are used for calculation of the dot product:

```
>> a=zeros(1, 1e6, 'double');
>> b=zeros(1, 1e6, 'double');
>> c=a*b';
```